# Recyclerview in android scroll moving on its own

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

**I have recyclerview contains many problem videos i have namely: when I click on any video move the list on its own down the list**

```
 recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    
            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In recylerview, you have a method called, `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`. Here, as the parameter, you can pass which position of the view do you want to show.